# Is there a way to connect to multiple firestore from the same .net application

Tags: c#, firebase

I have multiple DB in Firestore and I want to migrate from multi-service to monolith.
My code is written in .net, and I want to maintain the DB separation.

Unfortunately, I find no way to use multiple DB from the same .net application.
Does anyone know a way to do that? It's kind of weird that is possible through the SDK of other languages but not from the C# ...

*We use the official Google .net SDK for firebase

Comment: What code are you using to connect to Firebase at the moment?  It's hard to suggest something, when you don't give much information about what doesn't work.

Comment: If you see something that works the way you want with another SDK, maybe edit the question share that with us so we can see what you're trying to accomplish. Also wouldn't hurt to show what you have now. Right now it's hard to tell what you're doing.

Comment: @Neil it's not a code problem, is an SDK problem

Comment: @DougStevenson I added the requested info

Comment: How are you connecting to the FB DB? using `new FbConnection` ?  That takes a connection string, so is easy to have multiple connections.  That's not an SDK problem.  As I said, unless you post some code, we have no idea HOW you are using the SDK, so how can we suggest ways to fix it?

Comment: @Neil can you please add a link please to this functionality? the only `new FbConnection` I found is related to `FireBird` and not `Firebase` official SDK